# matching numbers with regex with specific requirement

Tags: regex

I would like to match following bold marked numbers in a Text with numbers and text.

*some text **12.444** **12,444** **12'444** **123.122** 12.1234 **12345** **1234** 12.12 12.1234567 12.242Text
**12.242** Text Text12.242 Text12.242Text*

Numbers with a dotlike seperators should only have 3 following digits. If number has more digits it should be ignored. The Number should be matched as a whole. 12.34567 should not match to 34567.

The Numbers should match as a whole so I could later match "from **12.123** to **56.789**" with 2 groups
group1 : 12.123
group2 : 56.786

I started with following regex which did not match the needs:

```
[?<!\d][0-9]{1,2}[,|\.][0-9]{3}[?!\d]
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the rule? Do you want to find `123.456` and `12`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?<!\S)(?:[0-9]{1,2}[,.'][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{3,})(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f751F9/2). **NOTE**: If the fractional part in the 1-2 digit numbers is optional wrap it with an optional group, `(?:[,.'][0-9]{3})?`:

```py
(?<!\S)(?:[0-9]{1,2}(?:[,.'][0-9]{3})?|[0-9]{3,})(?!\S)
```

Details:

- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand whitespace boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[0-9]{1,2}` - one or two digits
  - `[,.']` - comma, dot or `'`
  - `[0-9]{3}` -  three digits
- `|` - or

  - `[0-9]{3,}` - three or more digits
- `)` - end of the group
- `(?!\S)` - a right-hand whitespace boundary

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the square brackets that should be parenthesis, asserting not a digit on the left or right will still be true in case of a character like `T`

To match all bold values you could use:

```
(?<!\S)[0-9]+(?:[,.'][0-9]{3})?(?!\S)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert non a non whitespace char on the left
- `[0-9]+` Match 1 or more digits
- `(?:[,.'][0-9]{3})?` Match an optional decimal part with 3 digits
- `(?!\S)` Assert non a non whitespace char on the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4U8IWW/1)

The pattern will match either numbers with 3 decimals or 1 or more digits.